# how to use google sheets =importXML in Excel

Tags: excel, xml, excel-formula

using this code in google sheets, returns me the price.

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.mobilesentrix.com/oled-assembly-for-iphone-14-aftermarket-pro-xo7-soft","//*[@id='product-price-154113']/span")`

I have tried using

`=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://www.mobilesentrix.com/oled-assembly-for-iphone-14-aftermarket-pro-xo7-soft"), "//span[@id='product-price-154113']")`

but it only returns #VALUE!

Answer (score 0):

The tag on page looks like this

```
<div class="price-box">
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-154113">
<span class="price">$123.58</span> </span>
</div>
```